# How can I get p:selectOneMenu to calculate its width correctly inside dialogs?

Tags: dialog, primefaces, selectonemenu

When I embed a `p:selectOneMenu` in a `p:dialog`, its initial width is too small in Primefaces 3.4. The width of these widgets was perfectly fine in Primefaces 3.2. Do I need to do a hack to get around this?

The problem manifests in Chrome. The following example code demonstrates the problem:

```html
<p:selectOneMenu value="A" onchange="testDialog.show()">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Default item" itemValue="A" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Click here to show the dialog" itemValue="B" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:dialog header="Test dialog" widgetVar="testDialog">
  <p:selectOneMenu value="A">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="This one here in the dialog" itemValue="A" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="doesn't calculate" itemValue="B" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="its width" itemValue="C" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="correctly" itemValue="D" />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: What browser? I know the dialog's width is fixed when using IE.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I guess I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem; it's like the dropdown button is blissfully ignorant of the fact it's covering up the textbox.  On my setup I was able to get the selectOneMenus to appear properly with this CSS fix:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-selectonemenu label.ui-selectonemenu-label {
        padding-right: 28px;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
```

**Edit:** Oh whoops, I see this solution is very similar to akoskm's comment.  But I tried that at the time and `text-align: right` wasn't working for me; only `text-align: left` was leaving the characters uncovered.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `p:selectOneMenu` in the dialog with a div

```
<p:dialog header="Test dialog" widgetVar="testDialog">
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <p:selectOneMenu value="A">
            ...
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </div>
</p:dialog>
```

You can probably wrap the selectOneMenu with some primefaces component too, but I think you shouldn't use components to fix styling glitches.

Comment: I tried this, but the selectOneMenu doesn't expand to fill the div. I also tried styling the selectOneMenu itself with 100% width, but the text is right-aligned and the button covers up the rightmost few characters.

Comment: I missunderstod your problem an focused on the `p:dialog`. I don't what kind of styling you've used but putting some padding `<p:selectOneMenu value="A" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15px">` made the text to appear inside the selectOneMenu, no covered chars. Of course, the size of the padding may depend on your font size.